# Force using TLS 1.2

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

My server is using TLSv1.0 by default (as I understand) and I have to force to use TLSv1.2.

I have tried suggested approach:

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
context.init(null,null,null);
SSLContext.setDefault(context);
```

however that seems to did not solve my issue.

When I check used TLS I see following

```
SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket();
String[] protocols = socket.getEnabledProtocols();

// return [TLSv1.2]
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(protocols));

// return [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()));
```

Do I need to do something else to make sure TLSv1.2 is used?

Why SSLContext.getDefault().getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols() returns me 3 TLS protocols?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which server are you using and how did you configured it. Can you provide some details on your initial question?

Comment: `.getSupportedSSLParameters()` shows all protocols that JSSE implements thare aren't statically prohibited by the policy file; use `.getDefaultSSLParameters()` to see what is _enabled_ by default -- and is used in your socket, since it doesn't overide the context's default. By 'server' do you mean an actual TLS server, or a machine you call a server that is actually a TLS client? `SSLSocket` and `.createSocket()` are TLS clients not servers -- although the default protocols and ciphersuites apply to both directions.